# Looking for a book: $B(H)$ not reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book with a proof that for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, $B(H)$ is not reflexive. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is in Conway's Functional Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried finding it here http://books.google.de/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=reflexive&f=false but without success. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly this is not answer you requested, but may be this will be helpful for someone else.

We may regard $c_0$ as a closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}(H)$. Indeed, take any orthnormal basis of vectors $(e_i)_{i\in I}\subset H$ and for each $s\in c_0(I)$ consider bounded linear operator $T_s:H\to H$ well defined by $T(e_i)=s_ie_i$. Consider map $T:c_0(I)\to\mathcal{B}(H):s\mapsto T_s$. It is an isometric embedding, because [$\Vert T_s\Vert=\sup_{i\in I}|s_i|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642373/norm-of-diagonal-operator). Therefore $c_0(I)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}(H)$. Since $H$ is infinite dimensional, then $I$ is infinite. Take any countable $J\subset I$, then $c_0=c_0(J)$ is closed subspace of $c_0(I)$ and a fortiori of $\mathcal{B}(H)$. [Closed subspace of reflexive space is reflexive](http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/closed-subspaces-of-a-reflexive-space/), so if $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is reflexive, then so is $c_0$. But $c_0$ is not reflexive, so $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is not reflexive either.

Comment: Surely one of the simplest arguments and nicely put. If I recall correctly, Pedersen proves in Analysis Now that $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is the bidual of $\mathcal{K}(H)$ using the trace pairing, from which one can deduce the result as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more general fact: A C*-algebra $A$ is reflexive if and only if it is finite-dimensional. In the infinite-dimensional case, there is a normal element $x\in A$ with infinite spectrum (actually, [one can find a positive element with infinite spectrum](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Yt4pze-9rqwC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=C*-algebra%20element%20with%20infinite%20spectrum&source=bl&ots=pxMnUESjFB&sig=Rwoi-1AivPPxWeoOEzojUBRDWTg&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=arG-U-OlKIPIOafHgfgN&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=C*-algebra%20element%20with%20infinite%20spectrum&f=false)). Therefore, by the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), $C^*(x)$ is an infinite-dimensional commutative C*-algebra, hence of the form $C_0(X)$ for some infinite locally compact space $X$. Thus, there is a closed subspace of $C_0(X)$ (and in particular of $A$), isomorphic to $c_0$, hence $A$ is non-reflexive as this property passes to closed subspaces.

You will find other proofs of this fact in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112844/c-algebra-which-is-also-a-hilbert-space).

---

As for the reference, if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space with the [approximation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property), then $\mathscr{B}(X)$ is **not** reflexive. This is [Theorem 4 on p. 247](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NCm4E2By8DQC&lpg=PA247&ots=KhF5PxQFUD&dq=reflexive%20%22K(X%2CY)%22&hl=pl&pg=PA247#v=onepage&q=reflexive%20%22K(X,Y)%22&f=false) in

> J. Diestel and J. J. Uhl, Jr., *Vector Measures*, Providence, R.I., AMS, Mathematical Surveys, (15),‎ 1977.